# SwiftUI - NavigationView creates empty space on all sides of screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a Instagram like UI for practice. When I add a NavigationView, it kind of creates a empty border on all 4 sides of screen. Below is how the UI looks like -

[image]

Below is my code. What I might be doing wrong?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(MockData().stories) {
                        StoryView(story: $0)
                    }
                }
            }
            ForEach(MockData().posts) {
                PostView(post: $0, screenWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Image("instagram")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130)
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square.on.square")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

**.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)**

after the closing brace of NavigationView and the padding will be removed. If you want to remove navigation bar as well then follow the same by placing **.navigationBarHidden(true)**

So your code for removing padding will be:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(MockData().stories) {
                        StoryView(story: $0)
                    }
                }
            }
            ForEach(MockData().posts) {
                PostView(post: $0, screenWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Image("instagram")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130)
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square.on.square")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
            }
        })
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: @Pankaj is your issue solved by the above code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help, unfortunately this does not fix my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out above code of mine was good. I had issue with TabView from which this screen was shown. I had added padding to this View from tabview.